# Select element at different depths, Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, select, element

I have several forms on a page and i need to select all of the labels inside one of them. Some are in child elements for the form (p, div...).

What is the best way to do this?

```
var $labels = $('#subForm label'); // want all labels at different depths
var values = {};
$labels.each(function() {
    values[this.name] = $(this).text();
});
console.log(values);
```

Comment: are you getting any errors??

Comment: Your first line is already the best way to do it.

Comment: no errors & its only selecting the label whose direct parent is the form...

Comment: @danielCrabbe, this shouldn't be happening.  Can you post your html for the form please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have (`var $labels = $('#subForm label');`) works.

But a better/faster way to do it would be `var $labels = $('#subForm').find('label');`.

This is because the first method first searches for all labels in the DOM and then tests to see if they're descendants of the element with that id, but the second method finds the element with that id and then looks for labels amongst its descendants.

Comment: `$('#subForm').find('label');` would be faster.

Comment: wierd - there was some issue with jquery and it wasn't working as expected. Its not working fine! Thanks for your responses. Dc